# SimpleSAMLphp not redirecting on logout

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

SimpleSAMLphp is not redirecting me to my ReturnTo address the first time, it takes me to my IdP's logout page. If I click the logout link again, it takes me to my correct ReturnTo page. Any ideas on why this may be happening?

I am using `$as->logout("http://myurl.com");` to process the logout.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar case with solution that implement SAML protocol. I think the analogy may apply.
The logout scenario works on two steps.

1. The first step is to call into IDP server to perform the logout from its prospective.
2. if  IDP successful logout , then ,  it will redirect to the URL given.

The obvious reason is that IDP logout is not successful.

You should check errors in the login process or corruption in the login data after login.

I hope this help.